# Are RC cars on topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've wanted to build a small remote control car with a Raspberry Pi and a wireless controller to control it for a while now as a fun little computing project, maybe [something like this](http://tomre.es/post/lego-xbox-raspberry-pi/) but bigger and with gears, suspension, a more powerful motor and alike. It would definitely be powered by a motor of some sort and is technically still a car in need of maintenance (and repair if I then crash it)!

***Are questions about RC cars off topic for this site? If so, why?***

*Note:* Questions would be related to the assembly of the vehicle - not anything to do with the electronics, programming, shopping advice or anything else like that.

Comment: Interesting.  I have no idea though.  :-)

Comment: I'm not sure, either, but my gut check tells me no. I think it could be an excellent SE site of it's own, though. Maybe @BobCross would want to chime in on this?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it depends on the method of propulsion - if they have a petrol engine, and the question is about that, then it's not really any different to other small-engine questions, and we've decided they are on topic.

Questions about electrically powered cars, or the control systems, servos etc are definitely off-topic IMHO though. Of the current SEs, they'd probably fit best in Electronics, though they'd probably get migrated here for containing the word 'car' ;)

There was an Area51 proposal for RC models, but it's been closed: [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82797/rc-scale-modeling)